# django how to add image in JSONfield?

Tags: json, django

[directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gN5L.png) I want to add an image in JSONfield. Here is my json data:`

```
{"name": "some name", "image": "static 'ontheway/images/m1.jpg'", "overview": "some data"}, 
{"name": "some name", "image": "static 'ontheway/images/a1.jpg", "overview": "some data"}]
```

In the template I have done something like this :

```
{% for data in place.places_to_visit %}
    {% for key, value in data.items %}
       {% if key == 'image' %}
           <img src="{{ value }}">
       {% else %}
           <div> {{ key }}:{{ value }} </div>
       {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

The images are not getting displayed instead its path is displayed.
I have stored images in static files, do I need to store images in media?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store your images in `static` folder and then show them like this:

```
{% load static %}

<img src="{% static value %}">
```

Comment: updated the directory structure.Now I have added the image in static as you said and changed the path of the image . Still not working. What's  gone wrong?

Comment: @pratikjaiswal no, that's not enough. Please read about them [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/)

Comment: Went through it. Done! Thank you